# How to put bibliography under appendix

Tags: sectioning, bibliographies, appendices

I already have a reference put using `bibtex`. I need to put few of my references under appendix. I tried giving like this in my project report:

```
  \bibliography{biblio}
    \bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
    \appendix
    \chapter{List of Publications}
    \begin{thebibliography}{1}
    \bibitem{fo} Bob Tadashi Wakabayashi {\em Anti-Foreignism and Western
    Learning in Early-Modern Japan} 1986: Harvard University Press.
    \end{thebibliography}
```

But this put bibiliography separately under another page. And appendix is listed as List of Publications with a blank page and bibliography page comes just after that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming that you're using a `book` or `report` document class, add the [`etoolbox` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) to your document preamble

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
```

and then use

```
\appendix
\chapter{List of Publications}
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\chapter*{\bibname}}{}{}{}
\begin{thebibliography}{1}
```

If you're not using `thebibliography` anywhere else in the document, you could move the `\patchcmd{<macro>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}` construct to the document preamble. This way you keep document elements and formatting clean.

What is behind this correction? You'll notice that both [`book`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/book.cls) and [`report`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/report.cls) define the bibliography as a `\chapter*`, which opens up a new page - exactly what you don't want:

```
\newenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
     {\chapter*{\bibname}%
      \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\bibname}{\MakeUppercase\bibname}%
     %...
```

`\patchcmd` removes this from the environment. It also typesets the headers with `\bibname`. Not sure whether this is something you're after. Regardless, it can either be removed (with little hassle, similar to the above correction), or left in.

---

Of course, if this is the very last entry to your document, and you won't be using a `\chapter*` anymore, a simple redefinition should also work:

```
\def\@schapter#1{}
```

`\@schapter` is the starred version of `\chapter`, as defined in [`latex.ltx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx). If you have some other `\chapter*` commands following `thebibliography` (which is perfectly fine), you could also perform this modification locally by grouping it.